# `sudo` outputs strange message since update to 22.04 on wrong password

Tags: sudo, password, 22.04

Since release upgrade (update) to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS,

using `sudo`,
but *mistyping the password*, so using a wrong password,
leeds to the following additional output:

```
## any command seems to work, tried with `ls` or `apt-get update`
sudo ls 
[sudo] password for MYUSER:
When trying to update a password, this return status indicates that the value provided as the current password is not correct.
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for MYUSER:
```

The additional phrase "*When trying to update ... not correct*" seems to be a mismatch with other error messages in case of user failure?

If you need additional input, please let me know - I currently have no clue, where this comes from - but it makes no sense to me and looks like a bug to me.

- The machine is a vmware virtual machine (compatible to ESXi 5.0 and later, VM version 8), so close to a real metal;
  pure Ubuntu "server" install (headless/no-GUI, only ssh), but done a long time ago (12.04 LTS?) with `do-release-upgrade` every two years, as available.
- Usually I log into from a Windows notebook using sgTatham's `puTTY` and a key-file - so I need the password only for `sudo`
- therefore now I tried normal `ssh` Session from command window with password, but *stranger would it be*:

```
c:\>ssh -l MYUSER MYSERVER
MYUSER@MYSERVER's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
MYUSER@MYSERVER's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
MYUSER@MYSERVER's password:
When trying to update a password, this return status indicates that the value provided as the current password is not correct.
When trying to update a password, this return status indicates that the value provided as the current password is not correct.
When trying to update a password, this return status indicates that the value provided as the current password is not correct.
When trying to update a password, this return status indicates that the value provided as the current password is not correct.

Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-47-generic x86_64)

  System information as of Sat Sep 17 04:35:24 PM CEST 2022

  System load:  0.0                Processes:               189
  Usage of /:   52.5% of 29.38GB   Users logged in:         1
  Memory usage: 20%                IPv4 address for ens160: 172.31.***.***
  Swap usage:   0%

  => /srv/svn is using 91.0% of 334.55GB

0 updates can be applied immediately.

You have no mail.
```

- Logging in with the correct password gives same situation with `sudo ls` and wrong password as in the beginning.
- Logging in with wrong/mistyped password (above, 2 times) gives the additional *message after succeeded*, third try - but twice per failure (4x);
- repeating this with only one (1) wrong try gives only one doubled line (2x).

Comment: @user535733 just came to the same conclusion. Information about the system seems incomplete here.

Comment: updated: vmware virtual machine, only Ubuntu (server) install w/o GUI

Comment: The text of the error looks like something related to Windows (SMB?) authentication - see for example [HELP! lsass system error:When trying to update a password the return status indicates that the value provided as the current password is not correct](https://microsoft.wmlcloud.com/forums/t/100949.aspx) - do you have any non-standard PAM modules installed?

Comment: @steeldriver - well I see the coincidence, but text is different ("the return" vs. "this return") - so may be just due to a lack of variation using the same text in same situations - if have investigated and updated some access details above, but that seems to make no difference;
   so please if you have a clue for me, _where_ to look into or _what_ to report?

For me, the point is, that it happens right with the do-release-upgrade from 20.04 **to 22.04** - well, also other things happened during that change, like the change of php 7.4 to 8.1 - but leaving a defunct apache2 to the admin